# What type of military technology would develop in a water-covered world?

Tags: warfare, weapons, underwater

If there was a world of earth-like size and atmosphere completely covered by water with a sentient species, what would their military technology look like?

Assume high medieval level technology levels. So anything up to 1500 but no gunpowder. That would be difficult underwater anyway.

The species are roughly human size, and any body shape that could feasibly evolve in such a world. My preference is for them to swim. But other things like crawling over the surface or swimming above are acceptable.
**How would these creatures fight?**

Comment: This is a very broad question. What does "medieval level technology" even mean on a planet entirely covered by water?

Comment: No gunpowder, electronics, or any other technology developed on earth after 1500.

Comment: Gunpowder has been used extensively in the middle ages even before 1500 with cannons.
So does your species swim? You mention no islands.

Comment: @Mormacil they could be crab people walking along the bottom of an endless ocean, unaware of the surface above them.

Comment: Yes, the species swims.  The world is entirely covered by water, therefore it must swim or fly, and I would prefer it to swim

Comment: If this fits your answer better, then sure.

Comment: I said in the question "any body shape that could feasibly evolve in such a world"

Comment: Technology is way dependent on the needs of the user. And you don't give a clue about user. Humans needed fire to develop. Never mind a whole range of other lucky things that happened.

Comment: I suggest you write your species first to give us the constrains you want.

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad. We need more constraints on your species. Define who and what your sentient species is, and then this could be answerable. Voting to close as 'too broad.'

Answer (score 3):

"Medieval technology" is an Earth concept, and thus entirely useless to describe this water world, even with your caveat. Metal can't be forged when the heat required would boil the water around the smith, and the whole point of iron is that it can stand up to hammering when cool. And before anyone mentions it, no, heat vents on the ocean floor wouldn't work - the smith would still get cooked.

Now, that said, they'd still have weapons. Every high-intelligence creature (since the only one we know of is "humans," it's still true) has some form of delicate manipulator limbs, and delicate manipulators don't do well for combat. There would not, of course, be any fire - that pesky "surrounded by water" thing - and probably few chemically-derived weapons, given how hard it is to mix powders or liquids when everything is submerged in the universal solvent. There might be some poisons derived from sea life, something like a pufferfish on a stick, but they'd be risky to use. The risk gets worse when you realize that long weapons will get a lot of drag going through the water, so you probably don't want anything resembling swords or spears. In fact, what you'd probably want is some form of sharpened knuckles, made from naturally sharp-edged objects like shark teeth or chipped obsidian. A curved blade (or a wooden curve with sharp objects embedded in it facing out) with a grip directly under it would be useful for punching or slashing motions. These motions could be performed with only small motions of the manipulator limb, and would have a minimum of water drag. These would probably be the main weapon for generations of these creatures, simply because without metal and with severe water drag, the infrastructure to create anything fancier would be hard to come by.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with you about spears. They are our species primary underwater hunting weapon. We've been using them for thousands of years. Any species with similar physiology will probably develop something similar. Of course finding something long and straight for the shaft may prove difficult.

Comment: Yes, a stabbing motion would have very little drag, as a spear is extremely aerodynamic.

Comment: Okay, so yeah, a stabbing motion would work. However, humans have arms that can reach out quickly because our ape ancestors needed to be able to grab branches before they fell. The force of the extension is a side effect of the speed. It's unlikely that a purely aquatic creature would need rapid extension - waving motions to propel them through the water, grips because these are manipulators, yes, but probably not much in the way of rapid extension. Without rapid extension, spears wouldn't work for stabbing, and I described why slashing won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at Polynesia. They've fought extensively without metal weaponry. A water covered world would exclude a ton of inventions we'd have in medieval Europe. Underwater warfare is also an entire different beast.

- Arrows are out really. Modern spearguns would work but anything like a primitive bow? Won't work. Neither will blowpipes or slings.
- Slashing weapons like swords and axes won't work either.
- Metal equipment like plate armor won't work either. Rust, just rust. How would you even forge that underwater?
- Formations, tight infantry formations that have been extensively used throughout history require your men to stand still. Not gonna happen when you're swimming.

So what could work? Cavalry and spears. Mounting a larger fish. Perhaps something shark like but smarter. You could swim up to your enemy and as your shark pulls you past stab them with your Coral tipped spear.

Anything slashing though your create to much drag. So after stabbing with spears your people would rely on daggers and the like. Push daggers might be popular as they have minimal drag. Against that some form of light armor might evolve. Probably some hard arnimal skin or carapace.

Resources for weapons would be Coral, animal teeth and obsidian. Perhaps fibers woven into nets. But the drag would make using them awkward. Still pinned into a net would be a deadly place to be.

Comment: Good thought on the nets.  Maybe a few people pulling a very thin fibre net?  Made out of some kind of sharkskin or special algae.

Comment: I did not even thing about mounting sealife

Comment: I figure a domesticated shark would be a terrifying mount. Domesticated doglike Goblin Sharks, creepy.

Comment: Could you really domesticate an apex predator?

Comment: Of course we can. We domesticated wolves, foxes and cats. The latter aren't social animals to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

**Like cavemen**

I doubt they would get further than hand to hand combat (fin to fin? tentacle to tentacle?), simple weapons made out of some sort of sea life, like shells or teeth of a predator similar to [these](http://www.tikimaster.com/category/05.21/). If there was some plant that was analogous to a tree this stuff would be easier and you might get a pointy stick. It may also be possible to weaponize some poisonous or venomous sealife. Projectiles don't work well underwater so arrows and throwing weapons are out.

Underwater you get no fire so refining metals is out of the question, so anything derived from it will not appear